# how to edit /arch/x86/kernel/setup.c?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

i would like to add a print statement to this setup.c file and would like to see it in my messages when kernel executes start_kernel()...

```
     printk(KERN_INFO "m_name (put your name here): setup_arch(): command_line=%s\n",*command_line);
```

which would print

```
 my real name: setup_arch(): first_value_of_command_line
```

in /var/log/messages

i do have LXR and 14.04.1-Ubuntu

anyone can list steps here of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal  type following commands.

First you have to login as super user.

```
sudo su
cd /var/log/messages 
nano setup.c
```

this will open up setup.c file in nano editor.
then add the line you want to where ever you want .
after doing all the changes press CTRL+O  key combination to save the file.if it is asking for Confirmation give Y and press enter. then CTRL+X to Exit.

Done